# Haskell: Map and Zip A List

Tags: list, haskell, zip, syntax-error, tuples

OK, it seems I am just bad with haskell, I swear I keep getting stuck with all these questions. Anyways, I need to take two lists, zip them, and then map with the sum. So here is what I have so far and it is not working:

```
zipMapList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipMapList x y = do
    let zipList = zip x y
    let mapList = map + zipList
    mapList
```

Ok, and here is the error that I am getting when I try to load the file:

```
HW2.hs:18:25: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘(a1 -> b) -> [a1] -> [b]’
              with actual type ‘[(a, a)]’
• In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘zipList’
  In the expression: map + zipList
  In an equation for ‘mapList’: mapList = map + zipList
• Relevant bindings include
    mapList :: (a1 -> b) -> [a1] -> [b] (bound at HW2.hs:18:9)
    zipList :: [(a, a)] (bound at HW2.hs:17:9)
    y :: [a] (bound at HW2.hs:16:14)
    x :: [a] (bound at HW2.hs:16:12)
    zipMapList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] (bound at HW2.hs:16:1)
    18 |     let mapList = map + zipList    |                             
HW2.hs:19:5: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’
              with actual type ‘(a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]’
• Probable cause: ‘mapList’ is applied to too few arguments
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: mapList
  In the expression:
    do let zipList = zip x y
       let mapList = map + zipList
       mapList
  In an equation for ‘zipMapList’:
      zipMapList x y
        = do let zipList = ...
             let mapList = ...
             mapList
• Relevant bindings include
    zipList :: [(a, a)] (bound at HW2.hs:17:9)
    y :: [a] (bound at HW2.hs:16:14)
    x :: [a] (bound at HW2.hs:16:12)
    zipMapList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] (bound at HW2.hs:16:1)
19 |     mapList    |     ^^^^^^^
```

I just don't get what the error means, I mean I get a list [a] and another list [a] and then I zip them and map then and get another list, it doesn't make sense to me why I am getting tuple errors, can someone lend a hand?

Comment: "then map with the sum" - what does that mean? Can you add a sample input and output please?

Comment: [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] gets zipped to [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3,6)], then gets mapped to [5, 7, 9].

Answer (score 3):

`map + zipList` tries to sum `map` with `zipList`, as in `x+y`. There, you want to pass `+` as a function, so it should be `map (+) zipList`.

But wait. `zipList` is a list of pairs, and `(+)` does not take a pair as input:

```
-- simplified types for clarity
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
-- but we want
add :: (Int, Int) -> Int
```

A possible solution is to define our own `add`

```
add (x,y) = x+y
-- ...
map add zipList
```

or to use a lambda

```
map (\ (x,y) -> x+y) zipList
```

or to uncurry `+`:

```
map (uncurry (+)) zipList
```

Also note that your type is wrong, you need `a` to be a numeric type to sum.

```
zipMapList :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipMapList xs ys = map (uncurry (+)) (zip xs yz)
-- or, exploiting zipWith
zipMapList xs ys = zipWith (+) xs yz
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a function with type `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and `zip` has type `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`. When you write `map + zipList`, you are trying to add an element of type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` to an element of type `[(a,b)]` - can you see how this isn't going to work?

As to how you achieve what you want, this would be the algorithm:

1. Write an anonymous function or named function to sum the elements of the zipped tuple. Note, again what the type of the `(+)` function is - it does not work on a tuple, but two distinct inputs. Therefore, you need to separate the tuple into 2 inputs before you can do the addition
2. Apply `map` to the zipped list using the above function.

Comment: This is the problem I am having with haskell, I don't see how it is not going to work because shouldn't I be able to take a list and another list and then do some things to them and then return a list? In my head that is how I see it working, so when I see these errors I just don't get why it doesn't let me do that

Comment: Take a look at the type signatures. If nothing else, do they look the same "shape"? That should be a quick giveaway as to whether or not you can reason with both of them in the same way